# Иньекция MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим я знаю где находиться файлик с подключением к Базе Данных. Как я могу выташить из него к примеру исходник? Или допустим вытащить из него какие либо данные? [База](http://www.stars-speed.ru/blocks/bd.php).

Comment: если руки прогера прямые - никак. если есть примерная структура файла - кидайте, мож там баг какой найдем. А вообще в большинстве CMS - именно никак.

Comment: Да тут не речь о пряморукости, просто надо данные в теле скрипта хранить(что люди в зравом уме и рассудке и делают)<br>
В 99.9% случаев никак

Comment: нууу пример криворукости:

    mysql_connect($host, $user, $passwd) or die("Не удалось подключиться к $host с логином $user и паролем $passwd");

Он, конечно, "совсем песец", но я бы не сказал, что это совсем нереально. Или, например, при включенном register_globals проверка на `isset($admin)`, тоже бывает такое в говнокодах.

Comment: @Sh4dow Нет , Знакомый сделал по Попову сайт на php и вот хочу ему как бэ доказать что Попов не лучший учитель php :). Ломать мож и не буду а вот знанием какой нить секретной инфы думаю удивлю :)

Comment: А вы ему лучше найдите видеоурок по производству тринитротолуола, он тогда точно усвоит, что иногда книжки, даже школьные, лучше.

Comment: там все на code igniter значит написано...<br>
Я кстати не помню он `escape_string` делал там или не?^^<br>
Если не то вбей в гугл "пример SQL иньекции" и ломай наздоровье :D<br><br>
Но что-то я сильно сомневаюсь что там уж <b>настолько</b> непроффессионально все сделано...

Comment: >mysql_connect($host, $user, $passwd) or die("Не удалось подключиться к $host с логином $user и паролем $passwd");

если там **такое** написано, то врядли там настолько стоящее для траты времени по ломанию)
а можно еще написать
>mysql_connect($host, $user, $passwd) or die("Не удалось подключиться к $host с логином $user и паролем $passwd и с ftp доступом $ftpuser@$ftppass");

хД

Comment: @alexwindhope
@sh4dow      - Ломать пошли ? :)

Comment: мягко говоря лениво... Да и не люблю я рушить, входные данные `($_GET['cat'])` обрабатываются, дальше чето пробывать реально лениво, да и повторюсь - не люблю я это дело :)

Comment: @alexwindhope :( А жаль...Помог бы честному человеку чуток ломануть сайт... :DDDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если это тупо текстовый файл то просто открыть, если это, например, php скрипт и в нем прописаны эти данные то никак...
[sarkazm]зайти в панель управления хостингом и открыть ^^[/sarkazm]
Кстати а причем тут иньекции?

Comment: Эм как бы мне известен путь не в моём сайте :). А известен путь на сайте моего знакомого :). А как бы если я войду в его базу нестандартным путёмс и чёнитьс там поменяю :) это будет уже иньекция :).

Comment: это будет взлом, к иньекции это никакого отношения не имеет...<br>
Иньекция это когда не делают `real_escape_string`, как тут:<br><br>
<b>[sarkazm]</b> зайти в панель управления хостингом и открыть ^^ <b>[/sarkazm]</b><br>
Наличие слова `sarkazm` вам ниочем не говорит?:)

Comment: Не будет, вам в википедию, смотреть, что такое sql injection.

Comment: Fatahan Ога))) а если стоит глобальная фильтрация GET и POST запросов допустим с помощmю preg_match() и будет тот же die ("Умри мохнатая тварь");


Не нужно себя считать умнее других!

Comment: Говорит.....Но вот "если это тупо текстовый файл то просто открыть" - Внесло в мой рассудок мысль что Вы недопоняли что я хотел донести :)

Comment: Ребята <b>ВЫ О ЧЕМ?</b><br><br>
Цитата <b>Как я могу выташить из него к примеру исходник</b>, ппц причем тут SQL иньекция?<br>
<br>
цитата из википедии:<br>
<b>Внедрение SQL-кода (англ. SQL injection) — один из распространённых способов взлома сайтов и программ, работающих с базами данных, основанный на внедрении в запрос произвольного SQL-кода.</b><br><br>
И кому надо википедию читать? вообщем все с вами ясно ^^

Comment: Помог бы лучше а не помогал нашему мозгу понять что такое SQL injection :) Конечно спасибо за это...Но я обойдусь :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я отвечал на первый камент)

Comment: тогда сорри ^^<br>
Я уже подумал что все сума посходили...

Comment: Называйте как хотите ^_^ Главное помогите :)

Answer (score 0):

Ы) Допустим этом файлике прописано что-то типа:

```
defined("CONST") or die ("Умри мохнатая тварь");
```

Тогда точно никак)

Comment: Кстати, от чего такая защита защищает? Как она работает?

Comment: const объявляется в ядре движка, который уже отвечает за фильтрацию входа-выхода и показ ошибок, это защита от открытия файла "самого по себе" и включение его в обход движка. Иногда в этом движке так же проверяется "имеет лю юзер доступ к этому файлу", ну и много чего еще.

Comment: > Защищает от прямого вызова файла в
> адресной строке!
> 
> допути в index.php прописываем
> define("CONST", TRUE); а в
> functions.php defined("CONST") or die
> ("Умри мохнатая тварь"); в index.php
> подключаем файл functions.php и он
> выполняет работу на предмет если в нем
> находится echo 'string'; Если вызвать
> functions.php на прамую то будет Умри
> мохнатая тварь)
Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: P.S. Записывать нужно сразу после <?php